# Does [UIApplication sendEvent:] execute in a NSRunLoop?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsrunloop

I read this [apple doc about runloop](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/Multithreading/RunLoopManagement/RunLoopManagement.html):

> A run loop is an event processing loop that you use to schedule work and coordinate the receipt of incoming events... A run loop receives events from two different types of sources. Input sources deliver asynchronous events... Timer sources deliver synchronous events...

Now I know `performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:` and `NSTimer` run in a runloop.

The doc doesn't mention touch events as input sources. I wonder:

Q1: Do touch events sent by `[UIApplication sendEvent:]` run in some default runloop too?
Q2: If Q1's answer is YES, is that default runloop the same runloop handles `performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:` and `NSTimer` events?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I won't pretend on accurateness of my answer its only just my guesses.

What I will cover in this answer:

1. *Mach IPC/RPC. (Inter-process communication/Remote-procedure calling)*
2. *Project Purple. (iOS codename)*
3. *GraphicsServices. (Private Framework)*
4. *SpringBoard. (iOS GUI app)*
5. *Runloop itself. (It's role in all of this)*

---

I'm not really familiar with mach, (I'm planning to learn it more deeply in future) but I know basic primitives on which mach kernel operates. Mach kernel uses **ports** for communication between **processes** by sending **messages**. You can think of a process as your application.

---

***Project purple*** is simple codename for iOS. Why I mention this? Because there is a mach 'Purple system event' port which is used to send system event for ***SpringBoard*** application.

---

As I know there are private ***GraphicsServices framework*** which has:

- Checking for device capabilities. (Camera, Bluetooth, GPS, etc.)
- Get screen size/dimensions, orientation
- Presenting/Hiding/Managing keyboard
- And of course **sending events** (**touches**, volume setting, silent ringer switch, device locking, etc.)

GraphicServices framework is sending all events using mach 'Purple system event' port.

**Here you can look at its headers if you are interested:**

https://github.com/rpetrich/iphoneheaders/tree/master/GraphicsServices

---

iOS have application called SpringBoard that is what user see when navigating on his iPhone/iPad/iPod and it's responsible for launching applications, sending them events receiving notifications from them and so on. And I think that you've already guessed that SpringBoard receives events from Purple system event port and almost all of them are passed to active application. (There are some events that only related for SpringBoard, for example device locking.)

**For more information about SpringBoard look there:**

http://theiphonewiki.com/wiki//System/Library/CoreServices/SpringBoard.app

---

And now what's the role of ***runloop*** in all of that? If you look at the source code for `CFRunloopRef` you can see that it works tightly with mach ports. (*Source code can be found at : https://www.opensource.apple.com/source/CF/CF-476.10/CFRunLoop.c*)

When you call CFRunLoopRun it simply waits for messages from port(s).

[image: Application waits for messages from mach kernel]

On the given screenshot you can see that `UIApplicationMain` function calls GraphicServices framework infinity loop for running modally and waiting for events via call `mach_msg` that enters in trap : `mach_msg_trap`. It puts thread into sleep and wake up when new event arrives. Also ***UIKit*** as I see registers its own callback for events that ***SpringBoard*** deliver. We will see later in stack trace `PurpleEventCallback` and `_PurpleEventCallback` function calls on event arriving. This functions acts as a bridge between all GraphicServices and UIKit stuff. (I mean we receive GSEvent that is wrapped by UIKit in UIEvent, etc.) You can see that function names are easter eggs for 'Project Purple' codename.

As for ***UIKit*** I assume that it register its own `CFRunloopSourceRef` that invokes `_UIApplicationHandleEventQueue` function and handles such stuff as touches and other. (delegates them to your application) See screenshot (How is touch handled by system):

[image: Touching screen stack trace]

And when application suspends - ***UIKit*** invalidates this sources. Look at screenshot. (I've set symbolic breakpoint on `CFRunLoopRemoveSource` and as you can see in stack trace UIKit prepares to suspend application.) Then I choose `CFRunLoopSourceInvalidate` frame to find out if this run loop source is related to mach stuff. The `CFRunLoopSourceInvalidate` method has following prototype :

`void CFRunLoopSourceInvalidate (
   CFRunLoopSourceRef source
);`

So using lldb and having knowledge that arguments should be stored in a registers on method invocation I've printed out register values and read suggested argument to be related to mach stuff. As you can see - it's true.

[image: Invalidating runloop source]

---

***UIKit*** also notifies about successful launch, successful suspending etc. Whom it notifies? ***SpringBoard***. There is specific method that used to send events for specific mach port called `GSSendEvent()`. Port passed there is the application's event port. For more information look:

http://iphonedevwiki.net/index.php/GSEvent

Also some screenshots that demonstrate this communication:

Application finished its launching and reports this back to ***SpringBoard***:

[image: Application finished launching]

Application received event and you can see it's doing some internal things, setting status bar, instantiating view controller from storyboard, reporting back, etc:

[image: Some events handled by UIKit]

Suspending application call stack:

[image: Suspending application]

**Summary:**

***GraphicServices*** uses 'Purple system event' port to send events related to touches, device locks, suspending active application etc.
***SpringBoard*** receives messages from 'Purple system event' port and sends them to active application by getting its event port. ***UIKit*** receives them, handles them, and may sends result back to ***SpringBoard*** using ***SpringBoard*** event port.

---

Comment: Nice work! The call stack shows me that `sendEvent:` should occur in a runloop. :)

Comment: Now I have a further question: Is that runloop the same runloop handles `performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:` and `NSTimer` events?

Comment: Runloop just processing sources that **UIKit** set for getting events from **SpringBoard** (touches for example).
You automatically have **one** runloop per thread. So yes, this is the same runloop that processed your touches.

*performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:* and *NSTimer:* are some kind of *CFRunLoopTimerRef*. If you read further about CFRunloopRef you can see that it operates on 3 things - sources, **timers**, observers.

When you calling methods above : behind the scenes it just ads *CFRunLoopTimerRef* to current runloop.

Comment: should have a `__IOHIDEventSystemClientQueueCallback`?

Comment: Yep, you're right, just checked: active application receives touch event from SpringBoard and does callout to __IOHIDEventSystemClientQueueCallback, which in turn dequeues touch event and does callout to _UIApplicationHandleEvent

Answer (score 1):

Not necessarily. `performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:` and `NSTimer` will run on the runloop of the thread that called events them, whereas `sendEvent:` should run on the main runloop.